# How to handle 500 HTTP req/s to 3k servers as a client in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, architecture, reactive-programming

I'm creating an application that must send about 500 HTTP notifications per second. It's not so big number of requests, but there is a lot of application that I must connect to, so keeping connection open (keep alive or sth) is impossible.
Is there a better way than starts 200 threads and opening new http connection each time? Is Reactive programming  suitable in this case?

Comment: Use [WebClient](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient) instead of starting hundreds of threads.